# Reposicionar el botón con un área mínima

Tags: javascript

Actualmente tengo un js que hace que mi botón se reposicione y sea imposible (o casi) darle clic. La única forma de hacerlo es que el propio botón se reposicione encima del propio ratón.

Ahora intento evitar eso mismo, creando un área mínima de reposición. El caso es que no se muy bien cómo hacerlo...

No puedo usar las coordenadas del ratón como mínimo, porque si el botón está en una coordenada XY muy alta, el mínimo de generación sería también muy alto. Un valor fijo estaría bien. El caso es cómo pongo un mínimo.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    document.onmousemove = function(event){
    posMouse(event)
  };
    var btn = document.querySelector('.joker');
  btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      alert('Has hecho trampas');
    })
});

function posMouse(e){
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var btn = document.querySelector('.joker');

  tryToClicBtn(btn, x, y);
}

function tryToClicBtn(btn, x, y){
    btn.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{

        var rngX = Math.random()*x;
        var rngY = Math.random()*y;

        btn.style.top= rngX+"px";
        btn.style.left= rngY+"px";
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>007 : botón juguetón</title>
    <script src="js/007.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="joker" tabindex="-1" style="position: relative;">Pulsame</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quizás lo quieras mejorar evitando que se pueda ganar clicando la página, apretando tab y enter.

Comment: No se a qué te refieres ahora mismo. Si me lo explicas seguramente lo intente :D

Comment: Quiero decir que se puede ganar haciendo trampas, es suficiente clicar la página, luego con tab se enfoca el botón y lo podemos presionar con la tecla enter. Esto se puede evitar añadiendo el atributo `tabindex="-1"` al botón.

Comment: chachi!, lo apunto! gracias. Voy a editar la pregunta también

Comment: Se nota que en los juegos soy un cheater de primeras. :)

Comment: JAJAJAJAJAJJAJAJAJAJA pero mucho XDDD tramposillo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes simplemente definir una zona en la que el botón puede estar, por ejemplo 300x200 px, y olvidarte un poco de la posición actual.

Si quieres asegurarte de que no volverá a aparecer justo debajo del cursor, entonces sí puedes comprobar que la posición actual del ratón no está dentro del rectángulo que forma el botón, una vez recolocado. En el caso de que así fuese, puedes volver a recolocarlo.

```js
const LIMIT_X = 300;
const LIMIT_Y = 200;
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  const btn = document.querySelector('.joker');
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    alert('Has hecho trampas');
  });
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', moveButton);
  
  function moveButton(e){
    const mouseX = e.clientX;
    const mouseY = e.clientY;
    let newX, newY;
    do {
      newX = Math.random() * LIMIT_X;
      newY = Math.random() * LIMIT_Y;
      
    } while(isMouseOverButton(mouseX, mouseY, newX, newY));
    btn.style.top= newY + "px";
    btn.style.left= newX + "px";
  }
  
  function isMouseOverButton(mX,mY, x, y) {
    const rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
    const conflict = (mX > x && mY < (x + rect.width) &&
        mY > y && mY < (y + rect.height));
    if (conflict) { console.log("Habrá que mover de nuevo"); }
    return conflict;
  }
        
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<button class="joker" tabindex="-1" style="position: relative;">Pulsame</button>
```